# Can not send message via gmail smtp

Tags: java, email, gmail

I've got the following code.

```
  public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            sendMessage("hello");
        }

        private static void sendMessage(String s) {

            Properties props = new Properties();        

            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
            props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");        

            Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                }
            });

            try {               
                Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
                message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("myMail@gmail.com"));
                message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                        InternetAddress.parse("myMail@gmail.com"));
                message.setSubject("subject");
                message.setText(s);
                Transport.send(message);
            } catch (MessagingException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
```

Password and user name are valid. But exception is the only thing I've got:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/ContinueSignIn?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbtN2
534-5.7.14 -5TkN4GaweC6hf3rGNq9_jNkn3li8xHQJsvsrBtvsgYtTItKuGxzOh0JxrqqrtlGEKUfRj
534-5.7.14 ObHLIRLXI877ZwP120TCNTgXfCCj-sxKvs4LMuwQTm-MlRVj43NtxpqZAWM7MtzxwCde0w
534-5.7.14 -NrEnlwJVoqdYPvJjsbZyzN4wL-nETdGCAkC7wSOv_56NCEMh4riOM_M5AlR4Uf0FnsZB3
534-5.7.14 PdfTBLfznxA9Q6yesAh5ib8uebGU> Please log in via your web browser and
534-5.7.14 then try again.
534-5.7.14  Learn more at
534 5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 dz6sm720370lbb.17 - gsmtp

    at ru.tenet.es09.runnable.SendMailRunnable.sendMessage(SendMailRunnable.java:62)
    at ru.tenet.es09.runnable.SendMailRunnable.main(SendMailRunnable.java:32)
Caused by: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/ContinueSignIn?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbtN2
534-5.7.14 -5TkN4GaweC6hf3rGNq9_jNkn3li8xHQJsvsrBtvsgYtTItKuGxzOh0JxrqqrtlGEKUfRj
534-5.7.14 ObHLIRLXI877ZwP120TCNTgXfCCj-sxKvs4LMuwQTm-MlRVj43NtxpqZAWM7MtzxwCde0w
534-5.7.14 -NrEnlwJVoqdYPvJjsbZyzN4wL-nETdGCAkC7wSOv_56NCEMh4riOM_M5AlR4Uf0FnsZB3
534-5.7.14 PdfTBLfznxA9Q6yesAh5ib8uebGU> Please log in via your web browser and
534-5.7.14 then try again.
534-5.7.14  Learn more at
534 5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 dz6sm720370lbb.17 - gsmtp

    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport$Authenticator.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:809)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:752)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:669)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:317)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:194)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at ru.tenet.es09.runnable.SendMailRunnable.sendMessage(SendMailRunnable.java:60)
    ... 1 more
```

Two steps authentication is not enabled in my accaunt. What do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn on the "less secure apps" feature in gmail so that your code will be able to run. you can access that from your google [console](https://myaccount.google.com/security)

Other than that, you might want to update your code how to access the gmail API nowadays for java in [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/java).